# How to create MAPI Profile programmatically with C#

Tags: c#, c++, mapi

I see how to create a profile in C++ with this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306962 but have been unable to find how to do this is C#. Any thoughts or links on this?

Answer (score 1):

C# cannot access Extended MAPI. There used to be a library called MAPI33, but I don't think it is being developed or sold any longer.
You can use [Profman](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman.htm) (I am its author - available with the distributable version of [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption), of which I am also the author) - it is accessible from all languages that support IDispatch-friendly COM objects (that includes C# or any other .Net language).